# CSS - all media-querys in one file? or load separated CSS-files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, media-queries

what is the better solution:

1) make one CSS-File with all Media-Querys for all supported resolutions

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

2) make a CSS-File for every supported resolution and load them in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:240px) and (max-width:639px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tablet.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:1023px)" />
```

???

I mean, in attempt 2) there are more requests, but is that really that important?

Comment: Do you believe in `SASS`?

Comment: Every developer may have a different opinion on this, depending on the scenario too of course. There is no "correct" answer in my opinion...

Comment: should I? .. i mean, CSS is like the simplest thing on earth.. so when someone tells me he has made the simplest thing "more simple" then i can't stop myselft of thinking, what is wrong with that guy :)

Comment: Offtopic: If you use HTML5, the ` type="text/css"` is no longer needed. Cleaner code IMO :)

Comment: In development it's common to use multiple css files to maintain maintainability. Tools like http://gulpjs.com/ can compile them into one file, one normal and one minimized, while you keep developing in your separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to find a difficult balance**. On the one hand, you want to keep your requests as low as possible as HTTP1 doesn't allow multiple resources in one request and HTTP2 isn't as common as it will be.

**On the other hand, there is parse speed**. On a mobile devices filesize matters. It takes longer to parse (=*translate your css to an actual result*) compared to a desktop machine.

If you have a big file, say 500kb+, the extra request could be worth it (and, when you use your cache properly, will only take one download per cache period). Do try to minimize the number of files, e.g. don't make one for <320, <680, <768, <1024 etc etc. Split in two, *maybe* three files (unless you have a good reason to do otherwise).

**You could also turn it arround**. Some developers like to build mobile first, and then scale up to desktop sizes. Instead of changing css when you go smaller, you use `screen and (min-width:1024px)`. Then keep your mobile css in the main stylesheet, and give the browser version the 1024px+ file, which is often more capable so it'll have less effect.

And **don't forget about maintainability**. You have to maintain the code. If you split everyting into files, you're not making things easier for yourself. If the solutions you implement are minimal, you might want to reconsider, because difficult code will have a worse effect in the long run.

Comment: thanks :) .. good point with the filesize and bandwidth !

Comment: Downvoter, please explain instead of only downvoting, so I can improve the answer.

Comment: great answer .. thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Fewer requests is always favourable due to the nature of HTTP 1.1 (new TCP connections are established for each separate request which takes time).

I'd strongly recommend using as **few requests as possible** throughout your application. However, for CSS one could use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to compile several files into one single CSS-file. The same can be achieved in numerous ways with JavaScript, eg with online [tools](http://jscompress.com/).

The media query will not stop the request of the file, no matter the current screen size:

[image: Network requests when fetching resources]

It's also worth noting that [SPDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) and [HTTP 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) are well on their way of being available on most major browsers.

Comment: Well since browsers get more clever, they will only load the CSS matching the media query, which will be one request ... and to not download more content than necessary would be preferable